# Compiler can't find class method

Tags: java, class, methods

I have this problem a lot, but usually is presented as referencing a static method in a non static context.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class name_GameOfLife {

public class GameOfLife {

    char[][] board;
    int count = 0;
    int column;
    int row;

    public void getBoard(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {           
        //reads file and creates 2d array from file info                       
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    name_GameOfLife GameOfLife = new Coulson_GameOfLife();
    GameOfLife.getBoard("test.txt");
}
```

}

So yeah... What can't I call the getBoard method?

Comment: Basic google search reveals http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Why are you using a nested type at all? And what is `Coulson_GameOfLife`? This is very confusing code... and the violation of naming conventions doesn't help, either.

Comment: the `getBoard` method is part of the `GameOfLife` class while you create an instance of the `name_GameOfLife` class which you name `GameOfLife`

Comment: You really dont need the first class `public class name_GameOfLife {` because if you're not going to use any other classes inside then just take it out. My opinion is for you to use GameOfLife and create an instance of the class and use the `getBoard()` method from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, instance variable are defined in the following mannner

```
GameOfLife name_GameOfLife = new GameOfLife();
// Class variable name = new class constructor
nameGameOfLife.getBoard("test.txt");
instance variable.instance method
```

First, you need to have the type of the variable, then the variable name. And  in the assigning part, you have some different class name.

And instance methods should be called on instances, not by class name.